# Getting Key Error in traversing nested MongoDB(JSON) document

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am traversing a mongo document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b39cbd94a6"),
    "original_query" : "az",
    "posts" : [ 
           "comments" : [ 
            {
                "comment" : "",
                "commentator" : "Abd",
                "fb_id" : "1000"
            }, 
            {
                "comment" : "Sharjeel Usmani Alig Haider Ali Haider Saifullah Naseem Akhtar Alig Haider Ali Tanveer Khan Alig Imran Choudhary Nizampur Tarique Anwar Champarni",
                "commentator" : "Hi",
                "fb_id" : "1000"
            }],
           "like" : {
            "total" : "289",
            "reactors" : [ 
                {
                    "profile" : "",
                    "name" : "Ad ",
                    "fb_id" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "profile" : "https://m.facebook.com",
                    "name" : "She ",
                    "fb_id" : "100"
                }
             ]
     ]
}
```

I want to count the number of words in comment section but I am unable to even traverse comment section.Following is my approach.

```
result=db.post.find().limit(3)
for post in doc['posts']:
    for com in post['comments'] :
        pprint.pprint(com['comment'])
```

But I am getting key error in the second for loop.

Edit:
Output desired:

```
 Sharjeel Usmani Alig Haider Ali Haider Saifullah Naseem Akhtar Alig Haider Ali Tanveer Khan Alig Imran Choudhary Nizampur Tarique Anwar Champarni"
```

Edit:
I have accessed the id of like field using

```
for post in doc['posts']:
    if 'like' in post:
        for reactor in post['like']['reactors']:
            list_of_reactor_ids.append(reactor['id'])
```

Comment: You can achieve this using aggregation... Can you post the sample output

Comment: Edited,I have earlier used the approach of simple accessing as lists and dictionaries,Let me edit and demonstrate that too.

Comment: Do you want to count number of words in ***Sharjeel Usmani Alig Haider Ali Haider Saifullah Naseem Akhtar Alig Haider Ali Tanveer Khan Alig Imran Choudhary Nizampur Tarique Anwar Champarni***?

Comment: Yes,I want to count the number of words in that.I didn't edited the desired output as a count of words because I am not even able to print the comments,leaving counting aside.

Comment: so the answer should **21** for `"commentator" : "Hilal Khan"` and **0** for `"commentator" : "Abdullah Azzam",` ?

Comment: Yes,exactly,you are right.